# find active logged in users within the last X minutes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to find a way to track what users have been active on my site in the last 15 minutes.  I add the `update_last_active_status` function to certain actions a user can perform.  The `last_active_at` column is updated in the `User` model with the current time but how can I determine which users have a value in the `last_active_at` column that is less than 15 minutes from the current time?

```
# updates last_active_at column when a user performs certain actions on the site.
def update_last_active_status(user)
  user.update_columns(last_active_at: Time.now)   
end
```

How do I find a user that has a login time less than 15 minutes ago?  The below does not seem to be working.

```
  # finds if a user has been active in the last 15 minutes
    def is_user_active?(user)
      if (Time.now - 15.minutes.ago) < (user.last_active_at.to_f)
        true
      else
        false
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_user_active?(user)
  if user.last_active_at < 15.minutes.ago
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.